# pubsub利用時のPyInstallerのエラー

Tags: python, python3, windows

お世話になります。
Python3.7、Windows10 64ビット環境です。
PyInstallerでpubsubを利用したプログラムを実行ファイルに変換しようとしているのですが、下記のエラーが出てしまいます。
何か解決方法はありますでしょうか。

### ソースコード

```
import wx
from datetime import datetime
from pubsub import pub
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

class mainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, size = wx.Size(800, 400))
        self.SetTitle("時計")
        mainScreen(self)

class mainScreen(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        self.parent = parent

        self.clock_label = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "時刻")
        self.clock_text = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "", style=wx.TE_READONLY)

        vSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vSizer.Add(self.clock_label, 0)
        vSizer.Add(self.clock_text, 0)
        self.SetSizer(vSizer)
        self.clock_text.SetFocus()
        pub.subscribe(self.update_clock, "time_changed")
        self.clock_thread = Thread(target=self.clock_start)
        self.clock_thread.setDaemon(True)
        self.clock_thread.start()

    def clock_start(self):
        while True:
            now = datetime.now()
            wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, "time_changed", msg="%s:%s:%s" % (now.hour, now.minute, now.second))
            sleep(0.1)

    def update_clock(self, msg):
        self.clock_text.SetValue(msg)

app = wx.App(redirect=False)
MyApp = mainFrame()
MyApp.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

### 実行したコマンド

```
pyinstaller --clean --noconsole clock.py
```

### エラー内容

```
57 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4
57 INFO: Python: 3.7.3
58 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
（中略）
5507 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pubsub.core.py"...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 41, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 36, in walk_packages
  File "<string>", line 20, in walk_packages
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pubsub\core\arg1\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: Should not import this directly, used by pubsub.core if applicable
```

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「変換しようとした」際に実行したコマンド等も記載しておくと回答が得られやすいと思います。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。ソースコードと実行したコマンドを追記しました。

Comment: [PyPubSub 4.0.3](https://pypi.org/project/PyPubSub/) をインストールした際には、\pubsub\core\ のフォルダはありますが  \pubsub\core\arg1\ のフォルダはありませんでした。何か以前のプロジェクトの影響が残っていたり、古い版数の可能性が考えられるので、いったんアンインストール/フォルダクリア/再インストールしてから、再度試してみてください。

Comment: pypubsubをアンインストールして、フォルダを削除した後、再インストールしたところ、解決しました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントで指摘いただきましたが、pypubsubのアンインストールとpubsubフォルダを削除してから、再度pypubsubをインストールし直したところ、該当のエラーは出なくなりました。
ご迷惑をおかけしました。
ありがとうございました。